# Why does this lead to zero when integrating a non-negative function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

When I try to integrate this $\int_0^{1} \frac{\log ^2(x+1) \log ^2(1-x)}{x} \, dx$, it leads to 0.

And when I use `NIntegrate`, it turns into a positive number, which seems to be right.
[image: the figure shows the function is non-negative]

The codes are shown below.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Plot[Log[1 + x]^2 Log[1 - x]^2/x, {x, 0, 1}]
Integrate[Log[1 + x]^2 Log[1 - x]^2/x, {x, 0, 1}]
NIntegrate[Log[1 + x]^2 Log[1 - x]^2/x, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Setting $x=0$ and $x=1$ gives `Indeterminate` and `Infinity`. In v12.3.1 it doesn't return zero - it can't work out the integral.

Comment: Rubi and Maple 2021 fail with it, returning the input.

Comment: @flinty - with v12.3.1 on my Mac I get zero for `Integrate` (after a long wait).

Comment: Confirm  it in 12.3.1 on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: One can obtain an analytical expression for this integral thrugh `Integrate[Log[1 + x]^2 *x^k/x, {x, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> k \[Element] PositiveIntegers]` which results in `(1/(6 k))(-1)^-k (6 EulerGamma^2 + \[Pi]^2 - 
   24 k HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1, 1 - k}, {2, 2, 2}, 2] - 
   6 Log[2]^2 + 6 (-1)^k Log[2]^2 + 
   6 k HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1 - k}, {2, 2}, 2] Log[16] + 
   12 EulerGamma PolyGamma[0, 1 + k] + 6 PolyGamma[0, 1 + k]^2 - 
   6 PolyGamma[1, 1 + k])`.

Comment: @user64494:  Can you explain how that integral is equivalent?  On its face it doesn't appear to include the `Log[1-x]^2` factor, but maybe you've done some clever change of variables on it.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: We make use of the Maclaurin series for `Log[1-x]^2` at zero which can be found as the product of two series..

Comment: It would probably be worth sending this to [Wolfram's Product Feedback team](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback) to make them aware of the issue (if they aren't already.)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot answer why, but I can provide an analytical solution with MA. We have

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log ^2(1-x) \log ^2(x+1)}{x} \, dx=
\frac{1}{12} \int_0^1 \frac{\log ^4\left(1-x^2\right)}{x} \, dx
+\frac{1}{12} \int_0^1 \frac{\log ^4\left(\frac{1-x}{x+1}\right)}{x} \, dx
-\frac{1}{6} \int_0^1 \frac{\log ^4(1-x)}{x} \, dx
-\frac{1}{6} \int_0^1 \frac{\log ^4(x+1)}{x} \, dx.$$

Each of them can be correctly computed with MA

```
i1 = 1/12 Integrate[Log[1 - x^2]^4/x, {x, 0, 1}]
(*Zeta[5]*)
i2 = 1/12 Integrate[Log[(1 - x)/(1 + x)]^4/x, {x, 0, 1}]
(*(31 Zeta[5])/8*)
i3 = -1/6 Integrate[Log[1 - x]^4/x, {x, 0, 1}]
(*-4 Zeta[5]*)
i4 = -1/6 Integrate[Log[1 + x]^4/x, {x, 0, 1}]
(*1/6 (-(2/3) \[Pi]^2 Log[2]^3 + (4 Log[2]^5)/5 + 21/2 Log[2]^2 Zeta[3] +
   24 (Log[2] PolyLog[4, 1/2] + PolyLog[5, 1/2] - Zeta[5]))*)
```

Combining together we obtain

```
i = i1 + i2 + i3 + i4
```

$$4 \text{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (16)-\frac{25 \zeta (5)}{8}+\frac{7}{4} \zeta (3) \log ^2(2)+\frac{2 \log ^5(2)}{15}-\frac{1}{9} \pi ^2 \log ^3(2).$$

Comment: Could you ground that the integral under consideration equals `i1+i2+i3+i4` in order to complete your answer? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 Does `FullSimplify[Log[1 - x^2]^4/(12 x) + Log[(1 - x)/(x + 1)]^4/(12 x) -  Log[1 - x]^4/(6 x) - Log[1 + x]^4/(6 x), Assumptions -> 0 < x < 1]` which results in `(Log[1 - x]^2 Log[1 + x]^2)/x` provide the desired justification?

Comment: @JimB: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, now `Integrate[Log[1 + x]^2 Log[1 - x]^2/x, {x, 0, 1}]` returns the input.

Comment: And now `0` again, so this is a session depending result.

Comment: This helps me more -- in another way! What's more, could you please tell me how you can find the integral is equivalent to i1+...+i4? Thanks.

Comment: @SHBookP just to make sure I understood the question, you would like to know how to obtain the first or the last equation?

Comment: @yarchik well, the last one. I've learned from your previous comment that one can obtain i1+i2+i3+i4 = i /; 0＜x＜1. So my question is that how you obtained it reversely?(How do you find that i can be expanded in the form of sum of four integrals which can be integrated respect to special functions?)

Comment: @SHBookP You would do such a separation when solving the integral manually. The four integrals are easier to compute. It seems to be easier to MA as well. Concerning your second question, how they can be actually computed. These are popular integral types often discussed in math.stackexchange.com. Have a look at the solutions of simpler integral https://math.stackexchange.com/q/795867/435814 . If you ar interested in the manual solution, post your question there, you'll get the answer quick. For MA--post another question here.